Нейросеть Fooocus - проблемы с записью файлов на SSD
У меня есть 2 диска - один SSD на 500 гб (Диск С, Samsung SSD 980, на нём Windows 10), второй диск - HDD (Диск Д) на 1 ТБ под файлопомойку.
Недавно установил fooocus, распаковал архив на диск Д, так как понимал, что нужно будет много места для скачивания моделей, обучения ИИ и т.д,
в общем будут скачиваться доп. файлы для работы нейросети.
При запуске (через батник run.bat) и работе с нейросетью заметил, как 345 ГБ свободного места на SSD постепенно превращались в 330 ГБ свободного места, а после завершения работы
fooocus значение опять стало равно 345 ГБ.
Сделав поиск по диску С обнаружил, что на диске создавалась папка с временными файлами от нейросети, а после завершения работы эти файлы удалялись.
Вот какие действия я предпринимал, чтобы любые манипуляции с дисковым пространством проводились только на диске Д:

Запускал нейросеть через браузер, установленный на диск Д (скачал Firefox Developer Edition и указал путь установки в папку на диске Д).
Поменял расположение системной папки TEMP с диска С на диск Д. (Картинка ниже - то, что выводится в консоль батника при запуске)

Менял расположение Python с диска С на диск Д.

Возможно что-то из этого бессмысленно/что-то я делал неправильно.
Вопрос в следующем: можно ли (и если да, то как) что-то сделать, чтобы программа не трогала диск С и все манипуляции проводила только на диске Д?
И насколько вообще для SSD "вредно" такое количество создания и удаления файлов, уменьшает ли это ресурс SSD?
